# Want help to create view using some function or procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, mariasql

I have following database structure

**Table user**
user_id
travel_start_date
travel_end_date

**user_source_airport**
user_id
airport_id

**user_destination_airport**
user_id
airport_id

There are following relations available
1. An user can have multiple source airport
2. An user can have multiple destination

I want to create view with following columns
1. source_airport_id
2. destination_airport_id
3. travel_start_date
4. travel_end_date

where source_airport_id, destination_airport is a distinct combination with minimum travel_start_date and maximum travel_end_date chosen by users for source airport and destination airport

Please suggest how can this be achieved.

Comment: You don't need a view if there is an user input, you need stored procedure.

Comment: @ArnaudPeralta can you suggest a solution

Comment: @ArnaudPeralta unless the calling code just selects from the view with a WHERE clause attached. But yes a procedure might be a nicer encapsulation and potentially more re-usable.

Comment: @ManishShukla what part of "you need stored procedure" doesn't tell you a solution? You've been given the idea now. You can easily research how to create a stored procedure with parameters. What have you looked at? What have you tried? This is not a free create-my-solution service...we'll _help_ you with your code, not just take the requirements and write it all for you. For that you need to pay a freelancer or something.

Comment: How do you know which source airport matches a given destination, given that a user can have multiple of both? I _think_ your data model lacks the concept of trip - a user has 0...n trips, a trip has a start airport and a destination airport.

Comment: Neville is correct, it's a good point. But to extend it...even if you can establish the start and destination airport for a specific trip, how do you know whether the desired trip fits into the desired start and end dates? You don't seem to have any route maps. You don't know which airlines fly between which airports, or at which times. In the real world you certainly can't guarantee there is a direct flight between any two airports, and if not then you have to work out the most optimal connections. That then becomes a variant of the _travelling salesman_ problem...not simple to solve.

Comment: I don't understand the need for that schema.  Seems like you need a single table with user_id, start_date, end_date, source_id, dest_id.